# Riemann Hurwitz formula for Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

Let $F:X\rightarrow Y$ be a non constant holomorphic map between compact Riemann surfaces,
Then

$2g(X)-2=deg(F)(2g(Y)-2)+\sum_{p\in X}[mult_p(F)-1]$.

I am studying the proof from Rick Miranda's Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces.

Proof: Take a triangulation of $Y$ , such that each branch point of $F$ is the vertex . Assume that there are $v$ vertices , $e$ edges and $t$ triangles. Lift this triangulation to $X$ via the map $F$.

Here is my question.
If there is no branch point what will happen ?

Comment: Well, in the proof, you can actually take any triangulation with the set of vertices **containing** the branch points; the method will still follow!

Comment: Okay. Let me check if the proof remain same for that.

Comment: Doing triangulation in $X$ via $F$ is matter of worry.

Comment: The proof only requires that branch points be vertices, not that every vertex is a branch point. I don't see anything that goes wrong.